# Showing a new image inside existing axes w/o deleting the colorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, matlab-hg2

I am working on a GUI that is being initialized by creating several [`axes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) along with an invisible [`colorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) for each one (this is done so that axes maintain their predefined [`Position`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_position))<sup>[1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30986#answer_39465)</sup>. The handles to all axes and colorbars are stored.

Interactions with the UI may result in images being plotted on any one axes. I would like only the colorbar of the *active* axes to be shown at any given time, by appropriately setting the `Visible` property of all colorbars.

I am having a problem with this approach, because I'm using [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) to update my axes, and this deletes any colorbar associated with the axes, making the stored handles invalid.

My question is: **how can I use `imagesc` or `image` to update an axes that is associated with a colorbar, without the colorbar being deleted?**

Here's how to reproduce this problem:

```
dbclear in newplot %// Needed for the code to be properly re-runnable
%// Create an example figure containing a colorbar:
figure(); imagesc(imread('cameraman.tif')); colorbar;
%// "Refreshing" the displayed image:
uiwait(msgbox('The image will now be refreshed. A breakpoint will be set in newplot.m'));
dbstop in newplot at 124 %// The line responsible for deleting the colorbar in R2015A/B
imagesc(imread('cameraman.tif'));
```

The line on which the breakpoint in `newplot.m` is set reads:

```
cla(ax, 'reset', hsave);
```

Which is (un)surprisingly an undocumented way to invoke `cla` (with 3 parameters) that preserves objects whose handles are found in `hsave`.

---

Some ideas I had assuming colorbar deletion is inevitable (which I will pursue in case a "sane" solution is not found):

1. Binding a [`DeleteFcn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar-properties.html#property_deletefcn) to the colorbar that saves its data to some `struct`. Creating a new colorbar after `imagesc` has finished, then iterating over the fields of the `struct` and assigning all properties to the new colorbar object.
2. Check "every once in a while" that all colorbars exist using either `findall(hFig,'type','colorbar')` or verify that each of the axes has a valid `ColorbarPeerHandle` as per the Appendix below. Recreate the CB if invalid.
3. Delete all colorbars whenver different axes become active and create only the CB I'd like to show.

---

#### Appendix - ColorBar/Axes association:

- Handle to the colorbar associated with a certain axes `hAx` can be obtained (in hg2) using:

  ```
   hCb = getappdata(hAx,'ColorbarPeerHandle');
  ```
- Handle to the `axes` associated with a colorbar object `hCb` can be obtained using<sup>[2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311786#849951)</sup>:

  ```
   hAx = hCb.Axes;
  ```

Comment: Can you have access to the handle of the image object created by `imagesc`? I'm thinking you might be able to manipulate the `CData` property of it directly to update the figure.

Comment: @mikkola - I have access to all aspects of the axes, `Children` included. I do not recall why I haven't tried that.. Possibly because this means I need to write my own version of `imagesc` / `image` that does the update using the modification of `XData`/ `YData` / `CData` and doesn't have `cla`. Feel free to post that as a solution if it turns out to be much more trivial than I described just now (I'd really rather stick to using existing functions though)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a couple of solutions:

1. `safeUpdateImage1` - Based on the circumvention of `cla(...)` via the creation of a new `Image` object inside the axes after using `hold`. This is good for cases when an `Image` doesn't necessarily exist in the axes.
2. `safeUpdateImage2` - Following [mikkola's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906622/showing-a-new-image-inside-existing-axes-w-o-deleting-the-colorbar#comment55578842_33906622), based on updating an existing `Image` object. This is good for cases when there already is a `ColorBar` **and** an `Image` associated with the axes.

Here's a demonstration of both solutions alongside the original problem:

```
function [] = Problem
dbclear in newplot %// Needed for the code to be properly re-runnable
%// Create an example figure containing a colorbar:
Img = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure(); imagesc(Img); hAx = gca; colorbar;
%// Refreshing the displayed image (comment/uncomment as needed):
switch questdlg('Please select an image update method:','Update method selection',...
                'Broken','Safe1','Safe2','Safe1')
  case 'Broken'
    brokenUpdateImage(hAx,255-Img);
  case 'Safe1'
    safeUpdateImage1(hAx,255-Img);
  case 'Safe2'
  safeUpdateImage2(hAx,255-Img);  
end
end

function brokenUpdateImage(hAx,newImg)
uiwait(msgbox('The image will now be refreshed. A breakpoint will be set in NEWPLOT'));
dbstop in newplot at 124 %// The line responsible for deleting the colorbar in R2015A/B
imagesc(newImg,'Parent',hAx);
end

% For cases when the only desired child is an Image and the axes contents are unknown
function safeUpdateImage1(hAx,newImg,imgType,imgUpdateFcn)
if nargin < 4 || isempty(imgUpdateFcn)
  imgUpdateFcn = @imagesc;
end
if nargin < 3 || isempty(imgType)
  imgType = 'Image';  
end
if strcmp(hAx.NextPlot,'replace') %// Equivalent to checking "ishold == false"
  hAx.NextPlot = 'add'; %// Equivalent to "hold on"
  %// hCurrImgs = get(hAx,'Children'); %// Deletes all types of Children
  hCurrImgs = findall(hAx,'type','Image'); %// Deletes only graphical objects of type 
                                           %// "matlab.graphics.primitive.Image"
  for ind1=1:numel(hCurrImgs)
    delete(hCurrImgs(ind1));
  end
  imgUpdateFcn(newImg,'Parent',hAx);
  if strcmpi(imgType,'Image')
    axis(hAx,'tight','ij');    
%// 'tight' - XLimMode, YLimMode, and ZLimMode change to 'auto'. The limits automatic- 
%//           ally update to incorporate new data added to the axes. To keep the limits
%//           from changing when using hold on, use axis tight manual.
%// 'ij'  —   Reverse direction. For axes with a 2-D view, the y-axis is vertical with
%//           values increasing from top to bottom.    
  end
end
end

%// When it's known that the axes contains at least one Image:
function safeUpdateImage2(hAx,newImg,~,~)
%// <Input checking code>
hCurrImgs = findall(hAx,'type','Image');
%// <Optional code to decide which Image child to update>
hCurrImgs(1).CData = newImg; %// In this example, only update the "topmost" child
end
```

Comment: +1 This seems to work nicely. Good job on the case without an existing image. What you did for solution 2 is exactly what I had in mind, just didn't have the time to write up an answer.

Comment: @mikkola - After I saw that `XData` and `YData` were computed automatically, which means that you can replace an image with an image of different size w/o problem, I saw no reason not to include this solution. Thanks.